# API Requests when transitioning from premium to free tier of Google Maps

Tags: api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am planning to transition a website from using "Google Maps for Work" to the free tier of Google Maps, as the amount of traffic we are currently experiencing, doesn't justify keeping the paid tier. That being said, are there any changes to the implementation that must happen?

This [article](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/clientside/) indicates that if you're moving from the free to the paid tier then you must remove the key parameter from your requests. So should I assume that if I'm moving in the other direction then I have to add a key parameter? Do I need to remove my Client ID from the requests?

I didn't do the implementation, but have been assured by the developer that nothing needs to change, however, I'm a little nervous that when we flip the switch to the free tier something is going to break, if we don't make any changes to how the requests are made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely need to remove the client ID.  A key is not required, but is recommended to allow tracking of requests (and is required for some services, but you haven't specified what your map does/uses). If you are currently paying for "Google Maps for Work", my understanding is that comes with dedicated support, which would be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: Using a key is highly recommended.